# Robocopy Ext USB HD to Server 2008

Tags: security, network-share, robocopy

I tried copying data from an external usb drive to my W2008 server, g:\parent_directory d:\server_shared\parent_directory.  Unfortunately, I picked the "copyall" paramenter which copies over D=Data, A=Attributes, T=Timestamps, S=Security=NTFS ACLs, O=Owner info, U=aUditing info).

When finished, all folders and subfolders had a lock icon and there were "no security" settings assigned.  I tried messing around with changing the ownership, and security settings but it became a mess.  Deleted the parent directory from the server to start over.

Can anyone confirm that I should only use the default parameters, DAT in order to have the data copy over to the server without causing security issues when on the new server location?  Then I can assign access to appropriate domain security groups and then share the folder?
tnx

Answer (score 2):

I think you've pretty much answered your own question.

use `/COPY:DAT` and `/DCOPY:DAT`

DCOPY is for the folders, whereas COPY is for the files, so use both if you want them to all stay the same as original.

Run it via an administrative command prompt on the 2008 server.

Comment: Tnx for the reply.  What is the /DCOPY:DAT for please?  I thought /DCOPY is used with /dcopy:t for time stamps and that /dat also includes time stamps.

Comment: I think that's a typo?  The flag you would use is /COPY:DAT .  D = Data, A = Attributes, T = Timestamps

Comment: Sorry @jlehtinen - it was a typo on /DAT should be /COPY:DAT .  The /DCOPY:DAT is correct though and will maintain D,A,T for the folders themselves as they copy, not just the files.